# DNS resolution error when using OpenVPN v3 on Windows 11

Tags: windows, openvpn, windows-11

OS: Windows 11

Software: OpenVPN connect v3.4.3

I have a problem connecting to the VPN on AWS, I used the .ovpn file that was working on Windows 10 (OpenVPN Connect v2), but it always shows a resolution error: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0fbC.png)
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65N2d.png)

I have tried:

- set the DNS [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C05Yp.png)
- nslookup [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aERHH.png)
- disable the firewall

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/troubleshooting.html#resolve-host-name

Comment: 3.3.2 added support for local DNS resolvers. Do you have that? https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/openvpn-connect-for-windows-change-log/ https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=35006

Answer (score 1):

It works after downgrading the version to 3.2.3, maybe the server didn't accept the newest version